# Validar si existe un registro en una tabla DB y almacenar en una variable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando una consulta para validar si existe un registro en la base de datos, para esto empleó lo siguiente

declaro variable

```
decimal serie= 10002;//este valor corresponde a un ejemplo, la variable puede tomar cualquier valor
```

realizo la query

```
string sql2 = "SELECT codigo from tabla2 WHERE codigo=@serie";
```

mi intencion es capturar ese valor del campo codigo en la siguiente variable

```
var camp = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(sql2);
```

lo intente de esa forma, que debo modificar para que me capture ese valor en esa variable

Comment: Que es db.Database.Sqlquery??? que hace esa linea?? Podrias explicar un poco mas que cosa no anda en esa linea al final? que quiere decir capturar el valor? que valor? en que variable?

Comment: Para qué quieres capturar el código si ya lo tienes en una variable? Podrías explicarnos para entender mejor el escenario? Así podriamos ayudarte/aconsejarte mejor colega :)

Comment: Hola @Paulo solo es un ejemplo del codigo que estoy implementando, esa es una variable a la que asigne un valor para hacerme entender, en esa variable me recibe un numero cualquiera, puse uno fijo como ejemplo.

Comment: y lo que requiero hacer es establecer un if para indicar que si ese mismo valor existe en otra tabla pues suceda una cosa en caso contrario suceda otra

Comment: Yo no lo haría así probablemente,pero a priori parece estar bien. Que problema tienes con ese código? Te da algun error?

Comment: @pikoh en la variable `camp` quiero obtener el valor que se obtenga de la query, especialmente del campo codigo

Comment: Ahora que lo veo, es probable que te falte `.Single()` al final. `SqlQuery` normalmente devuelve una lista, si quieres un solo resultado como en este caso, debes especificarlo: `var camp = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(sql2).Single();`

Comment: @pikoh falla cuando La secuencia no contiene elementos

Comment: Claro. Usa entonces `SingleOrDefault` y comprueba. Si es null, el registro no existe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema imagino que es que `SqlQuery` normalmente devuelve una lista, pero en tu caso solo quieres un resultado.En ese caso, debes especificarlo. Hay varias maneras de indicar que solo quieres un resultado:

- [`Single()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.single?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Single__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)
- [`SingleOrDefault()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [`First()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [`Last()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [`LastOrDefault()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Cada uno de ellos tiene su funcionamiento. Los que contienen `OrDefault` te van a devolver el valor por defecto del tipo del `IEnumerable` en caso de que no encuentren ningún elemento. En tu caso, al ser decimal el valor por defecto será `0`.

Resumiendo, tu código debe ser algo como:

```
var camp = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(sql2).SingleOrDefault();
if (camp==0)
{
    //El registro no se ha encontrado en la base de datos
}
else
{
    //El registro ya existe en la base de datos
}
```

Comment: marque tu respuesta, porque con un par de modificaciones me ha funcionado. `camp` nunca sera `null`, sera el valor que encuentre de la consulta o en su defecto '0'.  Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @andrew_11 buf,tienes razón. `OrDefault` devuelve el valor por defecto del tipo, en este caso como le pasas `decimal` el valor por defecto es `0`. Modifico la respuesta para indicarlo